# input[type=date]: handling cross-browser widths and whitespace

Tags: html, css, html-input

Here's a default `input[type=date]` example in a few browsers:

[image: Screenshot of various browsers rendering input date type]

**Both Edge Chromium and Chrome add a lot of unnecessary whitespace to the default width of an input[type=date], about 50px to each.** In my particular case, I have a few of them in a very wide grid/table and the horizontal space is at a premium in order to fit all the complex form fields on the screen.

Ideally I would be able to use `width: max-content` to get those widths to tighten up, but that has no effect. (Or even better yet, that additional whitespace wouldn't exist at all by default.) If I set a specific width in CSS, all browsers start to overlap my date text around different values.

The only two options I can think of to fix my width problems are:

1. Browser-sniff and use different CSS selectors for different browsers. (I'm aware why this is bad practice and a terrible idea.)
2. Don't use input[type=date] and instead use a JavaScript datepicker or web component. (I don't love this because I think mobile browsers implement a much better datepicker than desktop browsers and I don't want to force one or the other on users.)

Anyone have any other suggestions? [Here's a CodePen](https://codepen.io/msoutherton/pen/eYJJjMO) in case anyone wants to fork.

Comment: So, use a JavaScript date picker for everyone except mobile, using media queries.

Comment: That works, and I hadn't considered it. Thanks. I just wish I didn't have to jump through hoops and import frontend components and customize it with media queries just for a silly basic thing, I guess. Maybe I'm just venting.

Comment: Considering we use to have nothing but text fields, this is an improvement :).